# Qt C++ QTcpServer выводит лишние подключения-удаления от QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt

Довольно непонятная мне проблема, описать её сложно, но постараюсь.

**Есть проблема только на некоторых компах - возможно где есть сеть между другими компьютерами**, на windows все хорошо, на linux подобных системах тоже все хорошо, но в linux пришлось использовать таймер, так как при connectToHost сигнал error срабатывает сразу, а не ждёт 3 секунды как на Windows.

Проблема в том, что если запустить сервер в момент когда идёт проверка соединения сокета с сервером слот:

```
connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(connectionErrors(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), Qt::DirectConnection);
```

происходит пауза, приблизительно думает 3 секунды и возвращает ошибку в этот слот, что подключиться не удалось. Если в этот момент думания включить сервер, он напишет что подключились, но когда 3 секунды пройдут мы упадём в слот что я описал выше и клиент закроет, удалит это подключение и подключит новое при следующем вызове функции где далее будет всё норм.

Так же бывает, что если выключить сервер (клиент будет много много раз пытаться переподключиться), то если снова уложиться в эти 3 сек он может выдать, что (клиент подключён, клиент подключён, клиент удалён, клиент удалён, клиент подключён), что даёт нам в вывод 2 фейковых подключения-удаления, а должно только последнее.

Прикладываю минимальные примеры клиент-сервера, возможно я, что то упустил?

**client.h**

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTime>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QDateTime>

#include <QTest>
#include <QDebug>

namespace Ui {
    class Client;
}

class Client : public QMainWindow
{ 
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Client(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Client();

private slots:

    // Подключение к серверу
    void connectedToServer();

    // Сообщение о подключении к серверу
    void connectionMessage();

    // Сообщение об отключении от сервера
    void disconnectionMessage();

    // Ошибки подключения
    void connectionErrors(QAbstractSocket::SocketError);

private:
    // Отсоединится от сервера
    void disconnectFromServer();

    QTcpSocket * socket;
    Ui::Client *ui;
};
#endif // CLIENT_H
```

**client.cpp**

```
#include "client.h"
#include "ui_client.h"
#include <QDateTime>

Client::Client(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Client)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    socket = NULL;

    // Подключение к серверу
    connect(this->ui->pushButton_connectedServer, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(connectedToServer()));
}

Client::~Client()
{
    delete socket;
    delete ui;
}

void Client::connectedToServer()
{
    // Если клиент уже подключен
    if(socket != NULL)
    {
        // Разорвать связь
        disconnectFromServer();
    }
    else
    {
        socket = new QTcpSocket(this);                                               
        socket->connectToHost(ui->lineEdit_ipAddress->text(), ui->spinBox_port->value());

        // Оповещение пользователя о подключении к серверу
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connectionMessage()));

        // Возможные ошибки при подключении
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(connectionErrors(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)), Qt::DirectConnection);

        // Приём и чтение данных с сервера
        // connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(slotReadyRead()));
     }
} 

void Client::disconnectFromServer()
{
    // Сообщение об отключении от сервера
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnectionMessage()));

    if (socket->state())
    {
        // Закрыть соединение
        socket->close();
    }

    // Удалить соединение
    socket->deleteLater();
    // Соединений нет
    socket = NULL;
}

void Client::disconnectionMessage()
{
    // Сообщение о выходи или отключении красным
    QTextCharFormat fmt = ui->textEdit_messageHistory->currentCharFormat();
    fmt.setForeground(QColor(255, 0, 0));

    ui->textEdit_messageHistory->setCurrentCharFormat(fmt);
    ui->textEdit_messageHistory->append(QTime::currentTime().toString() + " - Вы отключились от сервера!");

    fmt = ui->textEdit_messageHistory->currentCharFormat();
    fmt.clearForeground();
    ui->textEdit_messageHistory->setCurrentCharFormat(fmt);

    // Клиент отключён сменить имя кнопки
    ui->pushButton_connectedServer->setText("Подключится к серверу");
}

void Client::connectionMessage()
{
    // Сообщение о входе зелёным цветом
    QTextCharFormat fmt = ui->textEdit_messageHistory->currentCharFormat();
    fmt.setForeground(QColor(0, 171, 20));

    ui->textEdit_messageHistory->setCurrentCharFormat(fmt);
    ui->textEdit_messageHistory->append(QTime::currentTime().toString() + " - Подключение к серверу прошло успешно!");

    fmt = ui->textEdit_messageHistory->currentCharFormat();
    fmt.clearForeground();
    ui->textEdit_messageHistory->setCurrentCharFormat(fmt);

    // Клиент подключён сменить имя кнопки
    ui->pushButton_connectedServer->setText("Отсоединится от сервера");

    // Кнопка отправить данные доступна!
    ui->pushButton_sendData->setEnabled(true);
}

void Client::connectionErrors(QAbstractSocket::SocketError err)
{
    QString strError = "Ошибка: " + (err == QAbstractSocket::HostNotFoundError ?
                                     "Некорректно введён IP адрес." :
                                     err == QAbstractSocket::RemoteHostClosedError ?
                                         "Сервер отключён. Попробуйте соединится позже." :
                                         err == QAbstractSocket::ConnectionRefusedError ?
                                             "Невозможно соединиться с сервером" :
                                             QString(socket->errorString()));



    ui->textEdit_messageHistory->append(strError);

    if (socket->state() == QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState)
    {
        qDebug() << "state on 1 = " << socket->state();
        // Закрыть соединение
        socket->close();
    }

    socket->deleteLater();
    socket = NULL;

    // Переподключиться
    connectedToServer();
}
```

**server.cpp**

```
#include "server.h"
#include "ui_server.h"

Server::Server(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Server)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    socket = NULL;
    server = NULL;
    stopServer();

    // Запуск сервера
    connect(this->ui->pushButton_startServer, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(startServer()));
}

Server::~Server()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Server::startServer()
{
    if (server != NULL)
    {
        stopServer();
    }
    else
    {
        server = new QTcpServer(this);
        // Запуск сервера
        if (!server->listen(QHostAddress::Any, ui->spinBox_portNumber->value()))
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(0,
                                  "Ошибка сервера",
                                  "Невозможно запустить сервер: "
                                  + QString("Ошибка открытия порта %1. Возможно данный порт уже прослушивается."
                                        " Если хотите снова запустить сервер, то смените номер порта.").arg(ui->spinBox_portNumber->value())
            );

            stopServer();
            return;
         }

        // Сигнал срабатывает при каждом подключении нового клиента
        connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(slotNewConnection()));

        ui->pushButton_startServer->setText("Выключить сервер");
        ui->label_statusServer->setText("Сервер запущен");
        ui->label_statusServer->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(0, 171, 20); font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px");
    }
}

void Server::slotNewConnection()
{
    // Клиент подключён? возвратить его сокет
    socket = server->nextPendingConnection();

    if (socket != NULL)
    {
        // Если клиент отключён, разединён, оборвать связь с ним удалив его объект
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(clientDisconnected()));
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),
            this, SLOT(connectionErrors(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));

        // Сообщение о входе зелёным цветом
        QTextCharFormat fmt = ui->textEdit_messageHistory->currentCharFormat();
        fmt.setForeground(QColor(0, 171, 20));

        ui->textEdit_messageHistory->setCurrentCharFormat(fmt);
        ui->textEdit_messageHistory->append(
```

QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss") +
                                            " - Подключение клиента к серверу прошло успешно!");

```
        fmt = ui->textEdit_messageHistory->currentCharFormat();
        fmt.clearForeground();
        ui->textEdit_messageHistory->setCurrentCharFormat(fmt);

        // Получение запроса от клиента
        connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readingClientData()));
    }
}

void Server::readingClientData()
{
    qDebug() << "recived";
}

void Server::sendToClientMessage()
{
    qDebug() << "sending";
}

void Server::clientDisconnected()
{
    // Сообщение о входе зелёным цветом
    QTextCharFormat fmt = ui->textEdit_messageHistory->currentCharFormat();
    fmt.setForeground(QColor(255, 0, 0));

    ui->textEdit_messageHistory->setCurrentCharFormat(fmt);
```

ui->textEdit_messageHistory->append(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss") + " - Клиент отключился от сервера");

```
    fmt = ui->textEdit_messageHistory->currentCharFormat();
    fmt.clearForeground();
    ui->textEdit_messageHistory->setCurrentCharFormat(fmt);

    socket->deleteLater();
    socket = NULL;
}

void Server::connectionErrors(QAbstractSocket::SocketError err)
{
    QString strError = "Ошибка: " + (err == QAbstractSocket::HostNotFoundError ?
                                     "Некорректно введён IP адрес." :
                                     err == QAbstractSocket::RemoteHostClosedError ?
                                         "Сервер отключён. Попробуйте соединится позже." :
                                         err == QAbstractSocket::ConnectionRefusedError ?
                                             "Невозможно соединиться с сервером" :
                                             QString(socket->errorString()));

    qDebug() << "Error string = " << socket->errorString();
}

void Server::stopServer()
{
    if (server!=NULL)
    {
        server->close();
        server->deleteLater();
        server = NULL;
        socket = NULL;
    }

    ui->pushButton_startServer->setText("Запустить сервер");
    ui->label_statusServer->setText("Сервер не запущен");
    ui->label_statusServer->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0); font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px");
}
```